# How To Show Shared Data History using Ubuntu?

Tags: samba, shared-folders

I shared some directories using `Samba4.0` in my Ubuntu 12.04 system with guest permissions.

1. How could I know who accessed my share
2. Who have copied/moved some files from these directories
3. What are the files that had been copied/moved

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the log level in smb.conf : https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#LOGLEVEL
Then you can type `log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m.%U` in smb.conf to log per machine and per user.

Comment: could you please illustrate your answer